# T4 and RL-1 (Employment Income)

Tags: canada, income-tax, quebec

I'm filling my tax return using ufile. For T4 and Employment Income they have two options:

- T4 and RL-1 (Relevé 1) income earned in Quebec
- T4 and RL-1 (Relevé 1) with CPP contributions

What is difference? Which one should I fill out?

Comment: Without wishing to state the obvious, where did you earn the income? In Quebec, or in another province?

Comment: in Quebec, but actually they have another option: T4 income earned outside Quebec, so I think both these option related to Quebec. I just don't understand what 'with CPP contributions' means. It's additional contributions which I want to make or if it's included to T4?

Comment: CPP Is the Canada Pension Plan. You don't pay contributions to it in Quebec - you pay QPP instead.

Comment: if you write it as answer, I'll mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPP is the Canada Pension Plan, which is what the rest of Canada pays contributions to while Quebec pays to the QPP.

Answer (score 0):

You have to file them both separetly. Both Quebec and Canada income tax are not calculated the same: I have seem some small difference on some amount. 
That said, either if you have a good accountant or a good income tax software, they will make the right calculation. You really need to fill the right boxes and that is it. 
Hope that help. Feel free to edit.